# Unexpected Output with Lazily Generating Fibonacci Sequence in C++20 Ranges

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I am attempting to generate a Fibonacci sequence using the C++20 Ranges

the code was like:

```cpp
    auto fib_generator = []() {
        return [a = 0, b = 1](int _) mutable {
            std::tie(a, b) = std::make_tuple(b, a + b);
            return a;
        };
    };
    auto fibonacci = std::views::iota(0) | std::views::transform(fib_generator());

    for (auto i : fibonacci | std::views::take(6)) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
```

And it works correctly when printing from the 1st Fibonacci number, that is, beginning with 1.

`> 1 1 2 3 5 8`

However, when attempting to print Fibonacci numbers starting from the 5th position, it did not produce the expected result. Instead of starting with 5, the output still begins with 1.

```cpp
    for (auto i : fibonacci | std::views::drop(4) | std::views::take(6)) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
```

`> 1 1 2 3 5 8`

What i really want to do is sth works same as below

```cpp
    auto fib = [a = 0, b = 1]() mutable {
        std::tie(a, b) = std::make_tuple(b, a + b);
        return a;
    };

    int begin_with = 3;
    int took =10;
    for (int i = 1; i < begin_with + took; ++i) {
        if (i < begin_with){
            fib(); // run it, but dont return/execute
        } else {
            std::cout << fib() << " ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
```

It seems that the fib function is not being calculated for the elements that are 'dropped' using the std::views::drop.

It's efficient, after all, we don't need those values

But what if I want it to calculate those elements? Since they are necessary for computing the the following values...

I wonder why this code did not work correctly, and how can i fix it

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71148130

Comment: @273K sorry for the confuse, it is removed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use C++23 [`std::generator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/coroutine/generator) which has been implemented in GCC-trunk:

```
#include <generator>

std::generator<int> fib_generator() {
  int a = 0, b = 1;
  for (;;) {
    std::tie(a, b) = std::make_tuple(b, a + b);
    co_yield a;
  }
}

auto fibonacci = fib_generator() | std::views::take(6);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TWrWxqcYd)

Comment: Thanks, it's a nice feature to create a lazy producing ranges

Comment: @Jenway You should note that because of how powerful `std::generator` is, it requires a lot of overhead. It is not too difficult in this case to implement an iterator of your own: https://godbolt.org/z/Yn66xrrqc

Comment: @Artyer I see, thanks for your code, I learned a lot

Answer (score 1):

[`views::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view) requires the transformation to model the [`std::regular_invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/invocable) concept (with relevant argument types).

This concept requires that the transformation does not modify itself and that it is [*equality-preserving*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts#Equality_preservation), meaning simplified that it gives the same output for same inputs.

Your transformation violates both of these requirements and therefore its use as argument to `views::transform` has undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.  Is there a way to create lazy-producing ranges similar to iota that meet the required criteria? Should i create a struct with begin() and end() or what?

Comment: @Jenway See the other answer and also the linked question.